# Извлечение из разбитого на части архива с отсутствующими томами

Tags: archive

В случае, когда архив с текстовым файлом был разбит на тома и были утеряны некоторые части этого архива — можно ли как-то заглянуть по отдельности в имеющиеся части архива?

Answer (score 2):

*Пишу для winrar/rar, так как с описанной ТС ситуацией сталкивался при его использовании...*

Зайти внутрь архива и посмотреть на имя файла/лов можно. 
Прочитать файл - нет, т.к при чтении происходит распаковка во временную директорию, а у Вас не хватает томов. 
Функция восстановления в winrar часто не справляется с такого рода проблемами

Comment: Это старая база ВК от 28.07.10 в RAR-архиве, с текстовым SQL-файлом, имеется информация для восстановления. Отсутствуют второй и последний (8-й) тома. Выходит, что-то восстановить не удастся?

Comment: Вряд ли... Но попробуйте